# sendgrid set up with @sendgrid/mail

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

This error message pops up sometimes when I try to send emails with npm package sendgrid/mail. This works most of the times.

> { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 169.45.89.179:443
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1104:14)   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',   syscall: 'connect',
>   address: '169.45.89.179',   port: 443 } [bugsnag] Reported an
>   unhandled rejection… Error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 169.45.89.179:443
>       at SendGrid.send.then.catch.e (/home/leoqiu/foodnome-api/build/src/utils/emailHelpers.js:143:11)

My node server send it out with the following code:

```
export const sendVerifyMail = (to: string, token: string) =>
  SendGrid.send({
    to,
    from: { email: '..' },
    subject: 'Verify you..',
    dynamic_template_data: {
      header: 'Verify your account',
      text:
        'Please use the button below to continue the process.',
      c2a_link: `${serverAddress}/api/user-account/verify?token=${token}`,
      c2a_button: 'Verify'
    },
    template_id: 'd-0f6411434fbc4896bf389e3945affd5d'
  } as any)
    .then(d => d)
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      throw new Error(e);
    });
```

Comment: It seems email address is not real and email from sendgrid not delivered to inbox so status will be ```Bounced``` in sendgrid and request will be timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue with your code or on your side of the network, unless you had general connectivity issues at the same time.

ip 169.45.89.179 resolves to sendgrid's domain so this is probably an issue on their end, to double check this you could set up a continuous ping to 8.8.8.8 or run some other network monitoring set up to make sure your connection out is stable.

If your connection is not the issue, I would just report it to them along with any logs you are prepared to share, your source ip and the time the timeout errors occur would probably be useful to them

Comment: The weird thing is at stage, my site works just fine. I get email with exact same setting. But not on production. I am not sure what could be causing the issue.

Comment: does it fail 100% of the time in production ? Check that traffic from the production server is allowing traffic out to that port , run  'telnet 169.45.89.179 443' and see if it connects from your production server

Comment: you are right, it isn't connecting to my production, but it is to staging

Comment: do you know how to fix this?

Comment: it is probably a firewall rule set either on the server or the network, if there is a person responsible for the network they need to allow traffic out to the port

Comment: i disabled all ufw already. Anything else could be causing it?

Comment: is the production server on the same network or VPC as your staging server, does it have the same internet gateway  ?

Comment: I believe so, I just bought the same server 3 times, 2 for productions, 1 for stage. All of them run through cloudflare

Comment: and production servers run through a load balancer on cloudflare

Comment: I just tested 'telnet 169.45.89.179 443' on a generic aws ec2 instance and it is connecting out without issue, so it doesn't look like the end point is the issue, I would just open a ticket with cloudflare and see if maybe there are security features enabled just for production or maybe the load balancing is somehow screwing up the connection to sendgrid. If there aren't any networking rules on your production servers it must be something on the networks you're using

Comment: thanks, I tried with my other servers as well, and it all seemed to be working fine. Must be with load balancer is screwing things up. I will create a ticket and check